# PHPMyAdmin Upload Error 'file that is too large'

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I have just set up a droplet on Digital Ocean and am trying to import a SQL database that is 68 MB via PHPMyAdmin.

I've already increased the below on php.ini to 100x their default values...

```
memorylimit
postmaxsize
uploadmaxfilesize
```

The error I get is,

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to
>   documentation for a workaround for this limit.

However, the link to documentation doesn't go anywhere.

Any tips or suggestions to troubleshoot?

I imagine this is a fairly common problem, but everything I can find just refers to php.ini. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: an easy fix if you are on shared hosting is to split your sql file. there is loads of these  and you can do it on the fly online

Comment: I rechecked php.ini, and the values are what I had set for them. I didn't stop/restart apache but am able to open phpmyadmin. It just won't upload the file.

Comment: You *need* to restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to sql file folder. And open cmd console.

And type "type xxx.sql | mysql -u user -p db_name"

Ex: type 1.sql | mysql -u root -p task_db

And don't use powershell. Must use CMD.

If unknown 'mysql', Add system enivoriment mysql/bin path